# caffeinate can't keep display from sleeping

Tags: sleep-wake, high-sierra

I have a fleet of 7 macbook pro's running mac osx 10.10, 10.11, and 10.12, and 3 mac pro's running mac os 10.13 ("high sierra").
On all systems, I have set it to never sleep the system or display.
Oddly, that doesn't suffice, so I also use caffeinate to prevent sleep.
On the 10.13 systems, though, the display still goes to sleep, no matter what I try.  This affects two things:

- my opengl tests hang
- "osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to restart'" hangs

Since only the display is asleep, I can still ssh in and look around.

I currently run my script under caffeinate -dsiu -t 31536000, and when it hangs, evidently I've still got all the proper assertions going:

```
$ pmset -g assertionslog
2017-11-20 19:34:27 -0800 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
BackgroundTask 0
ApplePushServiceTask 0
UserIsActive 1
PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep 1
PreventSystemSleep 1
ExternalMedia 0
PreventUserIdleSystemSleep 1
NetworkClientActive 1
```

and yet the display is in DevicePowerState 1:

```
$ ioreg -n IODisplayWrangler | grep -i IOPowerManagement
| | "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"MaxPowerState"=4}
```

Executing another caffeinate -u wakes the display up and puts it into DevicePowerState 4 for 15 or so seconds, then it goes back to sleep and DevicePowerState 1, even if I give a longer timeout with -t. I've also tried repeating the -t argument after each assertion (in case the confusing manpage meant that).

To rescue "osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to restart'",
I have to issue "caffeinate -u".  "caffeinate -d" or "caffeinate -i" are not sufficient.

See my comments at https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/issues/92 for more details.

I guess I should use lldb to get a backtrace from a hung opengl test, figure out what API it's hung on, and then create a minimal app that sets the appropriate power management assertion, sleeps a bit, then calls the hanging API.  I'll try to do that when I get a chance.

To work around it, I currently have this in a background script:

```
while true
do
   caffeinate -ud sleep 10
done
```

but that's not enough; CurrentPowerState dips down to 1 frequently on
all systems (though I think only the 10.13 systems actually sleep the
display and hang my tests).

Has anyone else run into this?  Any suggestions how I can diagnose this further?

Comment: Have you considered trying a 3rd party app like Caffeine or Amphetamine for the 10.13 machines?

Comment: Second @jmh's sugggestion, but also add "Anti Sleep" (has a Z in a circle I believe) which seems to work on 10.13, though I haven't paid attention to the screen blanking as I was only concerned that the CPU didn't sleep (read: remote desktop from somewhere else).    But one question otherwise: if you're looking to have all these machines keep their displays operating, have you set the System Preferences -> Power -> Screen Sleep Timeout to "never"? If this is a bug in macOS that the timeout overrides the caffinated settings, then at least this would get around that for now?

Comment: I just use Apple's caffeinate because it should suffice, and I like to avoid 3rd party gui apps.  And yes, I set System Preferences to never sleep or blank the display.

Answer (score 1):

I found that caffeinate would not work for me in Catalina or Big Sur. I've found Amphetamine works just fine and I've had zero problems with it.

Comment: I use Amphetamine on my M1 Mac Air and find that it works perfectly as well.